# Database of known human proteins

Tags: proteins, research-tools

Is there an up-to-date database of known human proteins that is easily accessible using Python libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GenBank** includes human proteins and provides [APIs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25498/) for constructing HTTP requests to make searches. Examples are given in Perl, but if you prefer another programming or scripting language you are expected to write your own:

> Equivalent HTTP requests can be constructed in many modern programming languages; all that is required is the ability to create and post an HTTP request.

This approach has always served me well.

[**Uniprot**](http://www.uniprot.org/help/programmatic_access) seems similar in this respect.

**SwissProt** provides a [package for BioPython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SwissProt-module.html) which may be of interest. I don’t know if this is the library you are referring to — you don’t say, and I don’t use Python.

Answer (score 1):

The human proteome can be retrieved from the UniProt Knowledgebase (http://www.uniprot.org/help/human_proteome).

All data on the UniProt website is accessible programmatically via a REST API. The documentation http://www.uniprot.org/help/programmatic_access also includes a few python code examples (among other programmaing languages).

Please don't hesitate to contact the UniProt helpdesk if you have any additional questions.